# Read header values from excel to variable in ssis

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I have to read the header from the excel file and compare with DB structure just to ensure file format is correct before loading.
I created a **Excel Source plus** and unchecked "First row has columns" and I am reading only 1 row from excel. Now I have to store this into a variable so that I can compare with DB structure. 
I do not want to store them in a Record Set Destination as there are 48 fields in my file. Is there any other way to store this values in a variable or can it be achieved in script component?
Please help

Comment: I would do this in a script task.

Comment: Yea, I came up with a solution for those who are not good at C#. I read the header from file, standardized values in derived column and concatenated each into single column, created SQL query to get DB structure. in Lookup transformation I did lookup on both and redirected to no match, if it do not match. :) :)